# selectTab() selects the correct fragment but underlines the wrong(?) tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I have 4 tabs in the ActionBar (tab 0, tab 1, tab 2, tab 3). Each tab has its own fragment.
At some point in the application life I need to disable tabs 1,2 and 3.
Since there is no method to disable tabs in android, I use this code on `onTabSelected()`:

```
    switch( tab.getPosition() ) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContent, fragment, "0");
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(0));
        break;
    }
```

this to force the first tab to be always selected.
When tabs 1,2 or 3 are selected the fragment for tab 0 is selected alright, I see its layout displayed, but the lightblue line underlining the tab is not under tab 0.

Comment: confuz... Explain well..

Comment: @DhawalSodha I rewrote the question with more info, let me know if something is still unclear to you.

Comment: Are you implementing ViewPager and SectionPageAdater?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    case 3:
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(0));
        break;
```

for this

```
    case 3:
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
        break;
```